# trying to create a caption command

Tags: captions

Perhaps this is already done, in which case you can tell me the better way, but I would like to know what I am doing wrong.  I would like to create the following sequence of code:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{filename.png}
{ \small Fig. 1.54 A MOSFET is a terrible thing to waste }
\end{center}
```

Forgetting about the numbering for the moment (which I would like eventually) I tried to create a command to make this more compact:

```
\img[1][myimage.png][railroad bridge with reinforced sides]
```

The command attempting to make this happen:

```
\newcommand{\img}[3]{%
\begin{center}%
\includegraphics[scale = {#1}]{#2}%
{ Fig. 1.54 {#3} }%
\end{center}}
```

It dies on the next \end{ } so obviously I am doing something wrong.

I also tried passing in [scale=1] instead of just 1, and changing the newcommand:

```
\newcommand{\img}[3]{%
\begin{center}%
\includegraphics[{#1}]{#2}%
{ Fig. 1.54 {#3} }%
\end{center}}
```

As I said, I would like to know how to create a box and number them, so I am willing to take an answer that tells me which package I should be using, but I would also appreciate an explanation of what's wrong with my syntax as well.

Comment: Are you sure about your input/usage? You need to use `\img{.}{..}{...}`, not `\img[.][..][...]`.

Comment: Better use `\NewDocumentCommand` for this type of commands or use a `key-value` interface

Comment: There is of course, the existing `\caption` macro to do captions, and the `caption` package which gives more flexibility.  If you like the idea of a macro to set your figures, rather than an environment, my `boxhandler` package may be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with `\caption`, so I used it inside (well, better `\captionof` here.

The desired interface

```
\img[1][myimage.png][railroad bridge with reinforced sides]
```

enforces `LaTeX` to look for three optional arguments, this is 1st not really easy and 2nd error prone (the usage of `{...}` is wrong then, as well as the order of the arguments is difficult to remember)

Rather use

```
 \img[1]{myimage.png}[railroad bridge with reinforced sides]
```

with `\NewDocumentCommand{\img}{O{1}m+o}`, where the `+o` allows for long optional arguments and can be queried with `\IfValueT`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{caption}

\NewDocumentCommand{\img}{sO{1}m+o}{%
  \begin{center}%
    \includegraphics[scale = {#2}]{#3}%
    \IfValueT{#4}{%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \captionof*{figure}{#4} %
      }{%
        \captionof{figure}{#4} %
      }
    }
 \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\img[0.2]{ente}[A duck A duck A duck A duck A duck A duck A duck A duck]

\img*[0.2]{ente}[A duck A duck A duck A duck A duck A duck A duck A duck]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The starred version `\img*` omits the numbering.

Comment: Aren't you violating Paolo's copyrighted image? `;^)`  http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I don't know whether I violate Paolo's image, but Paulo looks different :-P

Comment: I am JOKING!  It is just that the duck and Paulo seem so... interchangeable.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Paulo is Schrödinger's Duck ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you like a macro form, rather than an environment form, I first show your result and 3 alternatives with the `boxhandler` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{boxhandler,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image}\\
{\small Fig. 1.54 A MOSFET is a terrible thing to waste}
\end{center}

or

\bxfigure[ht]{A MOSFET is a terrible thing to waste}
{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image}}

\captionStyle{n}{}
\bxfigure[ht]{A MOSFET is a terrible thing to waste}
{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image}}

\constrainCaptionWidth{\textwidth}
\captionStyle{n}{c}
\bxfigure[ht]{A MOSFET is a terrible thing to waste}
{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image}}

\end{document}
```

[image]